# A-Eye: Analysing Eye tracking Data

Tags: c, linked-list

I'd appreciate your advice.

data file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_UEM0TEmA_yeHJBZ0dzbV9Ca2c

[image]

```
/*
CNG213 Data Structures / Programming Assignment 1 - Sinan ULUSOY

"A-Eye: Analysing Eye tracking Data"


l1 is used for main list record 
l2 is used for sub list record
*/


#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


struct webNamesNode
{
    char StimuliName[50];
    struct webNamesNode *next;
    struct detailsRecord *dummyNodeOFdetails;
};


struct detailsNode
{
    struct detailsNode *next;
    int FixationIndex;
    int Timestamp;
    int FixationDuration;
    int FixationPointX;
    int FixationPointY;
};


struct webNamesRecord
{
    struct webNamesNode *head;
    struct webNamesNode *tail;
    int size;
};


struct detailsRecord
{
    struct detailsNode *head;
    struct detailsNode *tail;
    int size;
};




//create functions////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct webNamesRecord *makeMainList()
        {
            struct webNamesRecord *l1;

            l1 = (struct webNamesRecord *) malloc(sizeof(struct webNamesRecord));
            if (l1 == NULL)
                printf("Out of memory!\n");

            l1->head = (struct  webNamesNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct webNamesNode));  
            if (l1->head == NULL)                                                    
                printf("Out of memory!\n");                                          

            l1->head->next = NULL;  
            l1->head->dummyNodeOFdetails = NULL;
            l1->tail = l1->head;    
            l1->size = 0;           

            return l1;
        }


        struct detailsRecord *makeSubList()
        {
            struct detailsRecord *l2;

            l2 = (struct detailsRecord *) malloc(sizeof(struct detailsRecord));
            if(l2 == NULL)
                printf("Out of memory!\n");

            l2->head = (struct detailsNode *) malloc(sizeof(struct detailsNode));   
            if (l2->head == NULL)                                                   
                printf("Out of memory!\n");                                         

            l2->head->next = NULL;
            l2->tail = l2->head;
            l2->size = 0;

            return l2;
        }


        void makeNodeForMainList(struct webNamesRecord *l1, char StimuliName[50])
        {
            struct webNamesNode *insert = NULL, *temp;

            insert = (struct webNamesNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct webNamesNode));
            strcpy(insert->StimuliName, StimuliName);
            insert->next = NULL;

            l1->tail->next = insert;
            l1->tail = insert;
            l1->size++;
        }


        void makeNodeForSubList(struct detailsRecord *l2, int FixationIndex, int Timestamp, int FixationDuration, int FixationPointX, int FixationPointY)
        {
            struct detailsNode *insert = NULL, *temp;

            insert = (struct detailsNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct detailsNode));
            insert->next = NULL;

            insert->FixationIndex = FixationIndex;
            insert->Timestamp = Timestamp;
            insert->FixationDuration = FixationDuration;
            insert->FixationPointX = FixationPointX;
            insert->FixationPointY = FixationPointY;

            l2->tail->next = insert;
            l2->tail = insert;
            l2->size++;
        }
//create funtions END/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




struct webNamesRecord *load_data_points(char fileName[])
{
    struct webNamesRecord *l1;
    struct detailsRecord *l2;
    struct webNamesNode *temp;

    int FixationIndex, Timestamp, FixationDuration, FixationPointX, FixationPointY;
    int i;
    char StimuliName[50], previousStimuliName[50] = "web";
    char ch[50];

    FILE *eyeTrack;

    eyeTrack = fopen(fileName, "r");
    while(eyeTrack == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open the file \n\n");
        printf("Enter file name: ");
        scanf("%s", fileName);
        eyeTrack = fopen(fileName, "r");
    }


        for(i=0; i<6; i++)                  //reads first line in the file          
            fscanf(eyeTrack, "%s", ch);     

        l1 = makeMainList();    //makes main list and dummy node for it only one time

        //reads the file and put them into variables 
        while(fscanf(eyeTrack, "%d %d %d %d %d %s", &FixationIndex, &Timestamp, &FixationDuration, &FixationPointX, &FixationPointY, StimuliName) != EOF)
        {
            //in case of facing with screen or no media, skips those lines
            if( strcmp(StimuliName, "ScreenRec") == 0 )
                continue;
            if( strcmp(StimuliName, "No") == 0 )
            {
                fscanf(eyeTrack, "%s", StimuliName);
                continue;
            }




            //the most important part!!!//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            //compares web names to make node for main list and list record for sublist
            if( strcmp(StimuliName, previousStimuliName) != 0)
            {
                makeNodeForMainList(l1, StimuliName);
                l2 = makeSubList();
            }


            //starts to put values into sublist
            makeNodeForSubList(l2, FixationIndex, Timestamp, FixationDuration, FixationPointX, FixationPointY);


            //copies to use next round
            strcpy(previousStimuliName, StimuliName); 


            //makes connection between main node and sublist
            l1->tail->dummyNodeOFdetails = l2;


            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    }
    return l1;
}





void clean_data_points(struct webNamesRecord *l1)
{
    int threshold, removed=0;
    struct webNamesNode *tempForMainlist;
    struct detailsNode *tempForSublist;

    tempForMainlist = l1->head;
    tempForSublist = tempForMainlist->next->dummyNodeOFdetails->head; //goes l2 head

    printf("\nEnter a threshold value: ");
    scanf("%d", &threshold);


    //enters a loop for main link list to check all websites and enters inside loop to find values less than threshold
    while(tempForMainlist->next != NULL)
    {
        tempForSublist = tempForMainlist->next->dummyNodeOFdetails->head;

        while(tempForSublist->next != NULL)
        {

            //starts to hold node from head of sublist
            if( tempForSublist->next->FixationDuration  <  threshold )
            {
                struct detailsNode *remove;
                remove = tempForSublist->next;
                tempForSublist->next = tempForSublist->next->next;
                free(remove);
                l1->tail->dummyNodeOFdetails->size--;
                removed++;

                //changes tail if the node deleted is the last one
                if(tempForSublist->next == NULL)
                    l1->tail->dummyNodeOFdetails->tail = tempForSublist;
            }

            else
                tempForSublist = tempForSublist->next;
        }

        tempForMainlist = tempForMainlist->next;
    }

    printf("The number of fixations removed: %d\n", removed);
}



float total_fixation_duration(struct webNamesNode *aWebName)
{
    struct detailsNode *temp;
    float total=0;

    temp = aWebName->dummyNodeOFdetails->head->next; //goes first node in a sublist

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        total += temp->FixationDuration;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return total;
}



int count_fixation_points(struct webNamesNode *aWebName)
{
    struct detailsNode *temp;
    int count=0;

    temp = aWebName->dummyNodeOFdetails->head->next; 

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return count;
}



//converts like www.bbc.co to bbc
char *nameShorter(char website[50])
{
    int i=0, j=0;
    char *converted;

    converted = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

    while(website[i++] != '.');
    while(website[i] != '.')
        converted[j++] = website[i++];
    converted[j] = '\0';

    return converted;
}


//checks webname entered if it is in the list 
int isInList(struct webNamesRecord *l1, char pageName[50])
{
    struct webNamesNode *temp;
    temp = l1->head;

    while((temp=temp->next) != NULL)
        if( strcmp(nameShorter(temp->StimuliName), pageName) == 0)  
            return 1;

    return 0;
}




void show_page_statistics(struct webNamesRecord *l1)
{
    char website[50], converted[10];
    struct webNamesNode *temp=l1->head->next; //goes to first webpage

    printf("\nEnter a website name: ");
    scanf("%s", website);

    //exits if user enters a webpage that is not in the list
    if(!isInList(l1, strlwr(website)))
    {
        printf("ERROR: not in the list\n");
        return;
    }

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        //first gets rid of the part "wwww. .co  etc." and matches it with node thar has same page name
        if( strcmp(website, nameShorter(temp->StimuliName)) == 0 )
            break;

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("The number of fixations: %d \nThe total duration of fixations: %.0f milliseconds\n", count_fixation_points(temp), total_fixation_duration(temp) );
}



//these two functions check if coordinates of the node is in range
int isXinRange(int x, int topX, int bottomX)
{
    if(x>=topX && x<=bottomX)   return 1;
    else                        return 0;
}

int isYinRange(int y, int topY, int bottomY)
{
    if(y>=topY && y<=bottomY)   return 1;
    else                        return 0;
}

void show_AOI_statistics(struct webNamesNode *webName, int topX, int topY, int bottomX, int bottomY)
{
    int tempX, tempY, count=0;
    float total=0;
    struct detailsNode *temp;

    temp = webName->dummyNodeOFdetails->head->next;  //goes first node of sublist

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        tempX = temp->FixationPointX;
        tempY = temp->FixationPointY;

        //if points are inside of rectagle bordered by top x y and bottom xy, it calculates the statistics
        if( isXinRange(tempX, topX, bottomX)  &&  isYinRange(tempY, topY, bottomY) )
        {
            total += temp->FixationDuration;
            count++;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("The number of fixations: %d \nThe total duration of fixations: %.0f milliseconds\n", count, total );
}



//find webpage searched in main list and return it as a node in order to use it in other functions that request "a linked list of fixations"
struct webNamesNode *convertToNode(struct webNamesRecord *l1, char pageName[20])
{
    struct webNamesNode *temp;
    char converted[50];

    temp = l1->head->next;

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(converted, nameShorter(temp->StimuliName));   //converts like www.bbc.co to bbc 
        if( strcmp(pageName, converted) == 0 )               //finds StimuliName searched 
            break;
        else
            temp = temp->next;
    }

    return temp;
}




int main()
{
    int FixationIndex, Timestamp, FixationDuration, FixationPointX, FixationPointY;
    int topX, topY, bottomX, bottomY;
    int option;
    char fileName[20], pageName[50];


    printf("A-Eye: Analysing Eye tracking Data \n");
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);

    struct webNamesRecord *mylist;
    mylist = load_data_points(fileName);
    printf("The recording is successfully loaded ");
    beginning:
    do
    {
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\n\n\n------------------------\n");
        printf("Eye Menu\n");
        printf("------------------------\n");
        printf("1. Clean Data Points\n");
        printf("2. Show Page Statistics\n");
        printf("3. Show AOI Statistics\n");
        printf("4. Exit from A-Eye\n");
        printf("------------------------\n");
        printf("Enter your option: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        fflush(stdin);


        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                clean_data_points( mylist );
                break;

            case 2:
                show_page_statistics( mylist );
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\nEnter a page name: ");
                scanf("%s", pageName);

                if(!isInList(mylist, strlwr(pageName)))
                {
                    printf("ERROR: not in the list\n");
                    break;
                }

                printf("Please enter the top [X,Y] and bottom [X,Y] coordinates of the AOI: ");
                scanf("%d%d%d%d", &topX, &topY, &bottomX, &bottomY );

                show_AOI_statistics( convertToNode(mylist, pageName) ,topX, topY, bottomX, bottomY );
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("\nGoodbye! \n");
                break;

            default:
                printf("\nERROR: wrong entry!\n");
        }

    }
    while(option != 4);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nice question, it deserved more attention then it got when it was posted. It might have gotten more attention if you had only posted the contents of page 2 and page 3 (the program requirements).

It's not clear to that the modular programming requirement was met, since that might have indicated that the program should have been broken up into multiple C and header files and been built as a project in visual studio, eclipse or Xcode. The struct declarations at least could have been in header files. There could have been one C file for each of the structs which exclusively manipulated that particular struct.

It might have been easier to implement and debug the program if each of the `list` types (`webNamesNode`, `webNamesRecord` and `detailsRecord`) had common list functions such as `insert(node, list)`, `add(node, list)` and `delete(node, list)`.

**Possible Bugs**

There is a possible bug in `load_data_points()`, l2 may be used before it is defined in the following code:

```
        //the most important part!!!//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //compares web names to make node for main list and list record for sublist
        if( strcmp(StimuliName, previousStimuliName) != 0)
        {
            makeNodeForMainList(l1, StimuliName);
            l2 = makeSubList();
        }

        //starts to put values into sublist
        makeNodeForSubList(l2, FixationIndex, Timestamp, FixationDuration, FixationPointX, FixationPointY);
```

As a side note, the comment `//the most important part!` doesn't explain **why** it is the most important part.

A second possible future bug is that in the following code pointers are not initialized to `NULL`.

```
    struct webNamesRecord *l1;
    struct detailsRecord *l2;
```

If either of these pointers is tested for != NULL they may fail the test.

**Portability**

**Use Common Library Routines Whenever Possible**

The code is not portable because it uses the function `char* strlwr(char* str)`. `strlwr()` is only available some operating systems and the code may not link in some cases. See the first answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327812/strupr-and-strlwr-in-string-h-part-are-of-the-ansi-standard).

**Prefer powers of Two When Creating String Sizes**

There are many places in the code where the a character array is defined as

```
char StimuliName[50];
char previousStimuliName[50] = "web";
```

It might be better to size character arrays and strings on based word size, not doing so can sometimes result in memory alignment errors. At minimum use some power of 2 as a character array / string size. One possible way to do this might be:

```
#define CHARS_IN_WORD sizeof(int) // gives the number of characters in an int which is the basic C size.
#define COMMON_STRING_LENGTH        80 * CHARS_IN_WORD
```

or alternately:

```
#define COMMON_STRING_LENGTH        80 * sizeof(int)

char characterArray[COMMON_STRING_LENGTH];
```

Please note that using a symbolic constant such as `COMMON_STRING_LENGTH` makes it much easier in the future if the size of an array needs to change. This allows the code to be changed in only one place to change all of the arrays and change any `for` loops that may depend on the size. The words used might indicate what the number means as well which can help in debugging or if someone else needs to modify the code.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as **Magic Numbers**.

**Provide Enough Memory for a Full File Specification in a File Name or a Full Web Address**

In the function `main()` there is the following code:

```
char fileName[20], pageName[50];
```

There are 2 problems with this code, the first being that numeric constants rather than symbolic constants are used which may make it difficult to to resize these variables, the second and possibly more major problem is that these simply aren't large enough to hold the possible values of a full file specification or a full web page address.

A full file specification includes the full path from the root directory to the file, including the local file name. A windows file specification might be `C:\user\documents\FILENAME.EXT`. A Unix/Linux file specification might be `/Users/USERNAME/Documents/a-eye-analysing-eye-tracking-data/P1.txt`. The file to be opened may not be in the local directory and therefore enough space for the full path should be allowed. The size of fileName could quite easily cause the program to fail to load the file.

The same can also be true of a web page address, the page address is not guaranteed to be at the top level of the domain and generally the `http://` portion should be attached as well. As an example, the URL of this
question which is a web page is:

```
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146870/a-eye-analysing-eye-tracking-data
```

File systems differ on different operating systems. A symbolic constant such as `PATH_MAX`, `MAXPATHLEN`, or `FILENAME_MAX` can generally be found in one of the common header files (stdio.h for example) that defines
the maximum file name size allowed. This might be a good size to use for both the `fileName` variable and the `pageName` variable.

**The Use of typedef Might Help**

The [`typedef` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef) provides a way to declare an identifier as a type alias, to be used to replace a possibly complex type name. By using `typedef` in the `struct` declarations, the structs becomes types similar in some ways to `int`, `double` and `char`.

```
typedef struct detailsnode
{
    struct detailsnode *next;
    int FixationIndex;
    int Timestamp;
    int FixationDuration;
    int FixationPointX;
    int FixationPointY;
} DetailsNode;

typedef struct
{
    DetailsNode *head;
    DetailsNode *tail;
    int size;
} DetailsRecord;

typedef struct webnamesnode
{
    char StimuliName[50];
    struct webnamesnode *next;
    DetailsRecord *dummyNodeOFdetails;
} WebNamesNode;

typedef struct webNamesRecord
{
    WebNamesNode *head;
    WebNamesNode *tail;
    int size;
} WebNamesRecord;
```

Using the `typedef` statements above the following in the rest of the code:

```
WebNamesRecord *makeMainList()
{
    WebNamesRecord *l1;

    l1 = (WebNamesRecord *) malloc(sizeof(WebNamesRecord));

    ...

    return l1;
}

void makeNodeForMainList(WebNamesRecord *l1, char StimuliName[50])
{
    WebNamesNode *insert = NULL;

    insert = (WebNamesNode*) malloc(sizeof(WebNamesNode));
    strcpy(insert->StimuliName, StimuliName);
    insert->next = NULL;

    l1->tail->next = insert;
    l1->tail = insert;
    l1->size++;
}
```

**Inconsistent Function Naming Conventions**

The problem required six specific functions that were named in a particular style *verb*_*word*_*word*, this should have created a naming standard for all the functions in the program. So functions such as `makeMainList()` are inconsistent with the specified naming convention and probably could have been named `make_main_list()`.

Many companies have coding standards that require functions to be named in a specific manner. Once a naming convention has been established it is better to follow that convention so that other's that have to maintain the code can understand it better.

**Reduce Complexity, Follow SRP**

The [Single Responsibility Principle states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) that every module or class should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

Robert C. Martin expresses the principle as follows:

> A class should have only one reason to change.

While this is primarily targeted at classes in object oriented languages it applies to functions and subroutines in procedural languages like C as well.

There seem to be 2 functions that may be overly complex and could benefit by applying SRP, `main()` and `load_data_points()`.

The `main() function could be reduced in complexity by creating the function`execute_menu_loop(struct webNamesRecord *mylist)`. The`execute_menu_loop(struct webNamesRecord *mylist)`function would consist of the`do while`loop that might consist of 2 sub functions`int show_menu_get_option()`and a function to implement`case`3, perhaps`get_page_name_call_show_AOI_statistics()'. Among other things this will reduce the list of variables at the top of `main()`.

The function `load_data_points(char fileName[])` could be reduced in complexity by

- Creating the function`FILE* get_file_pointer_from_file_name(char *fileName)`
- Rather than scanning for individual variables using `fscanf()` scan an entire line from the file at one time using [`char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) and then use [`sscanf(str, "%d %d %d %d %d %s", &FixationIndex, &Timestamp, &FixationDuration, &FixationPointX, &FixationPointY, StimuliName)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) to parse the resulting string.
- Move the contents of the second while loop into it's own function.

**The Don't Repeat Yourself Principle**

In software engineering, [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is a principle of software development, aimed at reducing repetition of information of all kinds, especially useful in multi-tier architectures.

The following code is used in the program at least twice:

```
    if(!isInList(l1, strlwr(website)))
    {
        printf("ERROR: not in the list\n");
        // 1 control statement following
    }
```

Perhaps a new function should be added:

```
int check_list_membership(char *pageName, struct webNamesRecord *mylist)
{
    if (!isInList(mylist, strlwr(website)))
    {
        printf("ERROR: Web Page %s not in the list of data sources\n", pageName);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Usage :

```
if (!check_list_membership(pageName, mylist)) {
    // control statement return or break.
}
```

This ensures that the same error message will be used in both places and allow the error message to include the name of the webpage.

**Unused Items in the Program**

My compiler flags a number of variables that are unused in the program:

- In `main()` the entire first line declaring the integer variables FixationIndex, `Timestamp`, `FixationDuration`, `FixationPointX` and `FixationPointY` is unnecessary since none of the variables are used in this function.
- In `show_page_statistics()` the character array `converted` is unused.
- In `load_data_points()` the struct `webNamesNode` pointer `temp` is unused.
- In `makeNodeForSubList()` the struct `detailsNode` pointer `temp` is unused.
- In `makeNodeForMainList()` the struct `webNamesNode` pointer `temp` is unused.
- In `main()` the label `beginning` is unused because there is no `goto`.

All of these unused items tend to indicate the program is unfinished and may be buggy. It might be a better practice to create symbols as they are needed in the code, and delete symbols that are no longer used. Also having a label in the code may make one wonder why a `goto` was ever considered in the code.